# Sending email using SMTP in C# ocasionally times out

Tags: c#, email, smtp, timeout, exchange-server

I'm using the following code to send an email via MS Exchange server in a windows domain:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.Host = "mail.mydomain.com";
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.Timeout = 60000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@mydomain.om", "password");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@mydomain.com", "receiver@anotherdomain.com", "test", "test");
mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

try
{
      client.Send(mm);
      MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Faild: "+ex.Message);
}
```

In most cases this works fine & sends email with no problem, but after every 2 or 3 successful sending, it fails 1 or 2 times with timeout error (it times out after about 10 seconds that is much less than specified 60 seconds for client timeout in my code).
My mail server is MS Exchange & is located in same domain which is connected to client machine by LAN, so I think there is no network problem & it should cause by a configuration mismatch in client or server.
Any idea?

Comment: Why you use port number `25`?

Comment: @suji: This configurations given to me by server administrator, do you think it's wrong to connect on port 25?

Comment: I don't think so. i just asked for clarification. its quiet new for me while using `SmtpClient `

Comment: Just disconnect from the SMTP client when you don't need it and reconnect when you do. As suji said, there's a timeout value so you might as well account for this and save as much memory as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The SmtpClient class has no Finalize method, so an application must call Dispose to explicitly free up resources. If there's no help, you can check the setting about connection limit at exchange server.

Comment: what do you mean from connection limit exactly?

Comment: Maybe, you can try to dispose the client first.

Answer (score 0):

`SmtpClient.TimeOut` has a default value of `100 seconds(10000MS)`. but it can also be set through program since it is a property having `set` and `get`.

```
public int Timeout { get; set; }
```

It Gets or sets a value that specifies the amount of time after which a synchronous Send call times out. So you can try by `increasing` the timeout value since your method fails(throws exception) in some scenarios.
[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I told it fails after a shorter time than my current setted timeout, so its not a solution